# How to use constants in enum parameter values from the same file in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I got a situation in my project, in which I have to modify/refactor an enum file and to use better coding standards. I am even not allowed to create a new constant file or such.

Below is a sample of my problem-

```
    public enum Enumtricks {

        // 1. private static final String DESC = "A String";

        ELEMENT("A String");    // want to use constant DESC

        // 2. private static final String DESC = "A String";


        private final String description;

        private Enumtricks(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String value() {
            return this.description;
        }

    }
```

For both the cases I am getting errors, messages are-
1> Syntax error on token "String"
2> Cannot reference a field before it is defined

So, Is there a way to define constants & use them and to avoid String literals?

Comment: Any kind of help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I dont undestand your question. Please elaborate on A) what your goal is. B) what your problem is. Your code above looks ok the way it is. You cannot define constant string in an `enum`. And there is no need to do so, as your `ELEMENT` definition is just that.

Comment: I have lots of enum elements, so having lots of string literals, but I want to show all of them in the start or kind of a central place.

Comment: Also, I am not allowed to create another file for storing all the literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or add an interface outside of your `enum` but inside of the same compilation unit (= same file) as follows:

```
package test;

interface Constants {
    String DESC = "A String";
}

public enum Enumtricks {
    Enumtricks(Constants.DESC);
    private final String description;
    private Enumtricks(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String value() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

That way, you can group all your constants in front of your `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are very weird. If I understand correctly you would like to have several enums in one file. This in theory is possible like this - BUT I DO NOT RECOMMEND IT:

```
public class EnumCollection {

    public enum Enumtricks  {

        ELEMENT1("A String"),
        ELEMENT2("Another String"),
        ELEMENT3("Yet another String");

        private final String description;

        private Enumtricks(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String value() {
            return this.description;
        }

    }

    public enum AnotherEnum {
        EN, UM, SA, RE, CO, OL;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I dont want to create multiple enums in a single file. My enum is the parent file.

Comment: Anyways if I create a parent class and keep all the constants and also the enum in it, it will work. But then I have to access like- EnumCollection.EnumTricks.ELEMENT1

Comment: Yes you will have to do that. Thats why I mentioned that this is probably no good idea.

Comment: So to access the element we have to go one more level down. Will that be efficient to implement?

Comment: @53by97 No, this is usually a bad idea and against Java coding conventions. Best practice with enums is to have one file per enum (just like one file per class). You could have all your enum files in one package (folder). All the solutions given here are trying to stay within your given constraints. As said before it would be better to change those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I can get you to using Constants in the same file as your enums.

```
public enum Enumtricks {
    ELEMENT(EnumConstants.DESC);

    private final String description;

    private Enumtricks(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String value() {
        return this.description;
    }

    private static class EnumConstants {
        private static final String DESC = "A String";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it good to implement this in project(creating inner static class)?

Comment: You can use an outer interface either (it's a bit less private but otherwise trivial), but regardless of "good" or not, you have no alternatives within your constraints and it works, so go with it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting!